# Symfony/Strategy: formatting datetime based on timezone?

Tags: datetime, symfony1, internationalization, timezone

In a Symfony application...

1. What is the best way to store user's timezone information?

   - Is it found via the culture?
   - What are the standard keys that should be stored? Use PHP timezones and store as text?
2. How to format server datetimes on the presentation layer?

   - Are there PHP/Symfony helpers to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I use the following strategy:

- server datetime is UTC
- all dates are managed and stored in UTC
- user profile table has a timezone field of type text where is stored his PHP timezone
- user can set/change their timezone in their profile page (select widget is `sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceTimezone`)
- for displaying any date, I use a small helper `utcToLocal_date` which use the `format_date` function of the `Date` helper:

.

```
function utcToLocal_date($originedatetime, $format = 'g')
{
    if (class_exists('sfContext', false) && sfContext::hasInstance() && sfConfig::get('sf_i18n'))
    {
        $timezone = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getProfile()->getTimezone();
        if (!empty($timezone) && ($newtimezone = new DateTimeZone($timezone)))
        {
            $datetime = new DateTime($originedatetime);
            $datetime->setTimezone($newtimezone);
            $originedatetime = $datetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }
    }
    if (function_exists('format_date'))
    {
        return format_date($originedatetime, $format);
    }
    return $originedatetime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your first question.
I don't think a timezone for the user is stored, but of course you could.
But you should check the `default_timezone` setting under `.settings` in the `settings.yml`.

For formatting dates you can use the `Date` helper. Which in turn uses the `sfDateFormat` class, which is initialized with the current user **culture**.
You can also use this to display the timezone of a given date.

Comment: thanks Grad. But if I wish to store timezone, what is the preferred dataType, and what should I use as the master data? Any code snippet for sfDateFormat that takes timezone as input?

Comment: Preferred datatype depends on how you want to show it to your user. Of course the offset is enough to calculate, but if you want to present it to your user, a string would be better.
And I think there isn't a way to provide the timezone with the sfDateFormat constructor. I think you would have to create your own Helper (/class) to achieve this,  which should do nothing more than 'translate' the UTC time to a time in the users timezone (and then pass it to the DateHelper functions?). At least, that's how I would do it.